# How to differentiate error from 2 until-successful component in a single mule flow?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule-el

I am using mule version 3.9.

I am having a mule flow in which i am making 2 http calls to different URLs. First one is a retrieve call and then do some transformation and then i am calling the update api. I have put both API calls in individual until-successful components. I am using synchronous method.

In error handling part, i like to log which Api call was failed? Both http calls will throw same error "org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException".
I am not able to get url path info in the "exception.info" expression. Is there any other way to differentiate between these 2 http calls in error handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The until-successful scope consumes the error by design. To see them, move the requests each to a separate new flow (not a subflow), and use a flow reference inside the until-successful. The new flows have to be synchronous too. Flows have their own exception handling so they will log the error.

Reference: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-log-the-exception-thrown-inside-until-successful-scope